# Show a unique first names from the patients table that only occurs once in the list

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, having

Show unique first names from the `patients` table which only occurs once in the list.

For example, if two or more people are named 'John' in the first_name column then don't include their name in the output list. If only 1 person is named 'Leo' then include them in the output.

```
SELECT  first_name
FROM patients
HAVING COUNT(first_name) = 1;
ORDER BY first_name asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Your query needs a `group by` clause, that defines groups of records that should be aggregated together. Here, obviously you want to `group by first_name`.

```
SELECT first_name 
FROM patients 
GROUP BY first_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY first_name
```

Note that `COUNT(*)` is good enough here, as it counts how many records belong to each group; `COUNT(x)` is a slightly different thing, that counts how many non-`null` valuds of `x` exist.

Also note that `asc` is the default sort order, so it can be omitted.